# Jest/Enzyme | Ovverride defaultProps, for specific test

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I have a component that renders a button. I want to test, if that button click is setting the state to true, and the opposite, and also, if the modal is being rendered correctly.

I have some defaultProps, which wouldn't allow the component I want to render to render. If the `securityMode` is `''`, it should correctly not render the component. If it is IN `NORMAL` mode, it should render the component that has the Button that I need. The question is this:

**How to override defaultProps, for a specific test, in order to have the button rendered?**

Here is the Test-Code:

```
const defaultProps = {
  securityMode: '',
  listUsers: () => null
};

describe('UserOverviewScreen', () => {
  let wrapper;
  let listUsers;
  let openCreateUserModal;
  let closeCreateUserModal;
  beforeEach(() => {
    listUsers = jest.fn();
    notify = jest.fn();
    openCreateUserModal = jest.fn();
    closeCreateUserModal = jest.fn();

    wrapper = shallow(
      <UserOverviewScreen
        {...defaultProps}
        openCreateUserModal={openCreateUserModal}
        closeCreateUserModal={closeCreateUserModal}
        notify={notify}
        listUsers={listUsers}
      />,
      {
        disableLifecycleMethods: false
      }
    );
  });
```

The above runs `beforeEach()`. And below, the tests that fail:

```
    it('UserOverviewScreen, calls listUsers props function', () => {
      const response = {
        username: 'username',
        group: 'group'
      };

      console.log(wrapper.debug());
      wrapper.instance().onCreateUserSuccess(response);
      expect(listUsers).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });

    it('UserOverviewScreen, call openCreateUserModal when New User is clicked', () => {
      const button = wrapper.find('#new-user-button');
      const event = button.simulate('click');
      expect(event).toBeCalled();
      expect(event.state('isCreateUserModalOpen')).toBe(true);
    });

    it('UserOverviewScreen, call closeCreateUserModal when New User is clicked', () => {
      expect(wrapper.state('isCreateUserModalOpen')).toBe(false);
    });
```

Can someone help me correct these 2 tests and write the other one?

Comment: Why not move the component rendering call (`shallow(...)`) into the tests and pass the corresponding `securityMode` there?

Comment: I didn't really get what you mean, but even if I pass the securityMode like this: `securityMode="MYDESIREDSECURITYMODE"`, it gives me an error: `    TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined`, and even the `debug()`, doesn't work.. Can you elaborate..

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood the original question. I though the goal is to be able to pass different values of props (mainly `securityMode`) in each test, so that the tested component renders/does not render the button.

Comment: Yeah, because I passed securityMode as a prop, and I get the error you see above. I am not sure, why this is happening.. Basically can you write how to pass the securityMode as a prop. I don't think I am doing it wrong, though..

Comment: I agree, passing the prop like this looks ok. Where exactly do you get the error? It might be related to something different.

Comment: I get the error for each test, if I specify the securityMode as prop. After a couple hours of investigation, I have 2 possible scenarios. My first approach is to break up the testing into more modular cases, with different `shallowRenders` for each.  The second one, is to go to the actual component and investigate the scenario that the code there has some error.. Will post an update some time tomorrow... Thanks!!

Comment: hello, did u find a solution for this?  I'm seeing the same thing :(

Comment: Yes, create an extraProp flag inside the `describe`, you wish to change the props, and sperad them on top of the props, you already defined.